# How can 5 million message count come for 400k file upload in s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I have configured an AWS pipeline so that an object create event in my S3 creates an SQS message. I am using standard SQS queues. The problem surfaced last week when I noticed that 400k .3des files took a long time to get processed. The application logs showed that my code logic had to process nearly 5 million messages over 3 days but the aws commands showed only 400k files being uploaded and the AWS Console never showed message count higher than 500k.

My research indicates standard queues may create duplicate messages but then the message count should have been displayed in millions which it never did. I have not been able to replicate the problem yet for smaller datasets as every object upload creates a single SQS message.

I am out of ideas on what could be the likely cause.

Comment: A possiblity of SQS getting throttled when the events are fired from S3

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you where getting each message delivered over 10 times.  Since you mentioned application logs I'm going to assume you have a process running on a server somewhere.

My first thought was your application server started having performance issue and wasn't able process each SQS message before the timeout.  This would cause SQS to put the message back into the queue.

The question is how can you confirm this?  If you go into the SQS dashboard and select your SQS and then click on the Monitoring tab. Make sure to update you Time Range as it defaults to an hour.  Since this is over a week ago you might want to use CloudWatch->Metrics as you can create a absolute time range to limit the data to when your problem occured.

First lets confirm that the SQS metrics match your application metrics for the time window in question:
NumberOfMessagesSent: This should equal 400k. 
NumberOfMessagesReceived: This should equal 5 million.
NumberOfMessagesDeleted: This should equal about 500k.
ApproximateAgeOfOldestMessage:  This number should increase over the 3 days as the messages waited to be processed.

If you don't get these numbers then post your metrics as it will provide better insight.

A few more questions for you need to consider.
- How man receivers do you have?
- If you are not deleting messages until after they are processed then the  ApproximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisable metric should be close to the # of receivers.  If it is > then you application is not deleting the messages.   If it is < then it can indicate you application is not processing the messages before the timeout.

Pretty hard to tell you exactly what is going on, but hopefully this will help.